# Fill input fields from a browser's address bar

Tags: html, rfc

I know that if a form is with GET method, I can take "name" parameter from an input element and use it as a parameter in URL.

Example: https://www.google.com/search?q=form

This form has:

```
<input name="q">
```

Question: for a form with **POST** method is it possible to fill input fields from a browser's address bar?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: The question is not about JavaScript. It is about HTML.

Comment: Then I am fairly certain that the answer to your question is no, it is not possible. You can use JS to fill the form fields, but this is impossible using HTML alone afaik.

Comment: The question is not about JS. It is about anything else. Starting from security, and finishing at global problems. But it is in no way connected to JS. The question is important for me: I would like to understand what prevents it. It is security.

Answer (score 1):

The browser's address bar is always a GET and never a POST.